# Android IntentService only executes once

Tags: android, intentservice

I am using Android AlarmManger to schedule an IntentService to run after small intervals.

Here is my AlarmManger:

```
static void setNextSchedule(Context ctx, long interval){
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent nIntent = new Intent(ctx, DService.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1, nIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + interval, interval, pIntent);

        Log.i(ScheduleAlarm.class.getSimpleName(), "Next alarm set");
    }
```

And my IntentService:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(DService.class.getSimpleName(), "Service starting");

        ScheduleAlarm.setNextSchedule(getApplicationContext(), 15000);
    }
```

Currently it just holds code for testing. **Now this code will run successfully with no problems once the app starts but after 15 seconds it will state that the service is starting in the logcat but the code won't execute**.

How to get the intenet service the execute the code inside the `onHandleIntent` each time it runs?

Thanks

Comment: "but the code won't execute" -- what is "the code"? How have you determined that it "won't execute"? Why are you using a `getActivity()` `PendingIntent` for an `Intent` for a class named `DService`?

Comment: @CommonsWare - You are correct, changed to `getService()` and everything works fine now. Add as answer i will accept. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `PendingIntent`, the factory method needs to match the type of component that your `Intent` is for:

- If your `Intent` points to an activity, use `getActivity()`
- If your `Intent` points to a service, use `getService()`
- If your `Intent` points to a `BroadcastReceiver`, use `getBroadcast()`
- If your `Intent` points to none of the above, go directly to jail, do not pass Go!, do not collect $200 :-)